# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended for UPDATE command

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

My update command is throwing an exception

```java
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","Durga");
st = con.createStatement();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Bonus Amount : ");
int bonus_amt = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("salary range:");
float sal_range = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
int rowCount = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE employee SET esal = esal "+bonus_amt+ " where esal <" +sal_range);
```

Comment: save the sql command in a variable (`String sql = "UPDATE employee ...."`) and print it to see what it is looking like, before executing it. Also indicated to use a `PreparedStatement` instead of *injecting*  the values directly into the command, see [Exploit of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) (and [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables))

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a SQL string. Learn how to properly use a PreparedStatement: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/

Answer (score 2):

From your query `String`: `"UPDATE employee SET esal = esal "+bonus_amt+ " where esal <" +sal_range` I assume, you're missing an operator after `set` keyword, something like this:

```
"UPDATE employee SET esal = esal + " + bonus_amt + " where esal < " + sal_range
```

otherwise you would get query like this: `"UPDATE employee SET esal = esal 1 where esal < 1"`.

P.S.: I forgot to mention, that composing the query `String` yourself might be dangerous due to sql injection.